# Mobius transformation between those two domains

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, mobius-transformation

I am trying to understand why there is no such mobius transformation from $A$ to $B$ .
$$B= D_1(0) / 0 , A=\{z \mid \operatorname{Im}(z)+\operatorname{Re}(z)>0\}$$

I do not understand how do I approach this kind of problem. what contradiction do I get if there will be exist one? I would also like if some one can help me how to visualize domain $A$.

Comment: $A$ is just the half-plane above the diagonal $f(x)=-x$, seeing $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: A simple (!)  argument: $A$ is simply-connected, while $B$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

The half-plane $A=\{z \mid \operatorname{Im}(z)+\operatorname{Re}(z)>0\}$ is a $-\pi/4$ rotation of the upper half-plane, i.e. $A = e^{-i \pi /4} \mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H} = \{z \mid Im(z) > 0\}$. Therefore, we can build ourselves a Möbius transformation $T:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}/\{0\}$, and simply apply another Möbius transormation beforehand, namely $T':A\rightarrow\mathbb{H},\; z\mapsto e^{i \pi /4}z$. Our final answer will then be $T \circ T'$, once we find our $T$.

When given $\zeta \in d\mathbb{H}$ and $w\in\mathbb{H}$, there exists precisely *one* biholomorph Möbius transformation that maps $\mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ with $\zeta \mapsto 1, \; w \mapsto 0$ on the [extended complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) $\mathbb{C}\,\cup\,\{\infty\}$, namely
$$
T(z) = \frac{(z - w)(\zeta - \overline{w})}{(z-\overline{w})(\zeta-w)}.
$$
Note that this Möbius transformation maps $\zeta \mapsto 1, \; w \mapsto 0, \; \overline{w} \mapsto \infty\;$ (check this yourself!).

Herein lies the contradiction. We wish that $T:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}/\{0\}$, which is equivalent to $T:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$  with $\infty \mapsto 0$ in the extended complex plane. The "point at infinity" $\infty$ can be reached by travelling infinitely far in any direction. This implies (with a slight abuse of notation) $\overline{\infty} = \infty$ (again, please do not read into that too far).

We wish therefore to map $\infty \mapsto 0$, but also $\infty \mapsto \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know another approach wich does not include cross ratio? we did not learn this cross ratio theorem so I assume there is another way

Comment: Another approach would be to observe the inverse transformation $T^{-1}: \mathbb{D} / \{0\} \rightarrow A$. We wish to have the pole of $T^{-1}$ be at 0. This means $T^{-1}$ is of the form $T^{-1}(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c}\frac{1}{z}$. From here one can quickly see that there is no choice of b and c that would map all of $\mathbb{D} / \{0\}$ to $A$. There will always be a point mapped outside of $A$, so there is no biholomorphic Möbius transformation that satisfies our constraint.